# Guessing game in R

Tags: r, integer

I've tried to create a guessing game in R but it gives me the error with "readinteger". Just started learning R, sorry if it's a too simple question. The idea of the game is to ask a user to choose a random integer from 0 to 10 and if he guesses say something "well done" and if he does not say something like "It's bigger" or "It's smaller" until he guesses the integer.

```
> num <- round(runif(1) * 10, digits = 0)
> guess <- -1
> 
> cat("Guess an integer between 0 and 10.n")
Guess an integer between 0 and 10.n> 
> while(guess != num)
+ { 
+   guess = readinteger()
+   if (guess == num)
+   {
+     cat("Well done,", num, "is correct.n")
+   }
+   else if (guess < num)
+   {
+     cat("It's bigger!n")
+   }
+   else if(guess > num)
+   {
+     cat("It's smaller!n")
+   }
+ }
Error in readinteger() : could not find function "readinteger"
```

Comment: You haven't defined a function called `readinteger` and you're calling `readinteger()`

Comment: Maybe you want `readline()`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want `readline()`? I'm guessing you want [this](https://www.rexamples.com/4/Reading%20user%20input). You need to define that function in your script.

```
readinteger <- function() {
  n <- readline(prompt="Enter an integer: ")
  return(as.integer(n))
}

num <- round(runif(1) * 10, digits = 0)
guess <- -1
...
```